# Excel Formula for Combining SumIF with an Exchange Rate

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to sum sales for each country (easy) but also convert the various currencies I operate in at the same time. I am thinking this is best accomplished by a nested if function but I can't figure out how to write it.

I want the formula to add up each countries sales and edit the currency to GBP based on the referenced exchange rate

Any help much appreciated!

[image: Sum and convert]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$3:$B$15=B18)*($D$3:$D$15)*(SUMIFS(G:G,F:F,$C$3:$C$15)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you try to sum sales for each country and convert the currencies in the same time (base on GBP) use this

```
=SUMIF(B3:B15,B18,D3:D15) * VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(B18,B3:D15,2,FALSE),F3:G5,2,FALSE)
```

[This the sample of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOvHW.jpg)

and drag down the formular

Comment: This only works if the country and currency always match, which for Austria it does not.

Comment: Oh i see that 's the problem

Comment: May be need to convert before sum it's more easier

Comment: In the data provided by the OP Both Belgium and Austria use `GBP` and `EUR` and as such your VLOOKUP will only return the first and as such it will apply the wrong multiplyer to some of the lines.  Canada uses both `USD` and `GBP`.  In your data set change D7 to `a` it will not change the totals.

Comment: Yes, MarioS answered with the use of a helper column which will work, but I am not a fan of helper columns if one formula can easily do the work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this formula to convert the sales in Column E:

```
=IF(C3 = "EUR", D3 * $G$4, IF(C3 = "USD", D3 * $G$4,))   ..drag this down
```

Then I would use a SUMIF formula

```
=SUMIF($B$3:$B$13, B16, $E$3:$E$13)   ..drag this down
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert both ranges to Excel Tables, do a VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH to bring the exchange rate through to the table on the left, add another column to do the currency exchange, then make a PivotTable out of that Table, and bring in the fields you want to summarize by and report on. Look at this answer on how to make Tables and PivotTables: [VBA to copy data if multiple criteria are met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51211178/vba-to-copy-data-if-multiple-criteria-are-met/51214172#51214172)